# When i run rake db:create ,Error rake aborted! uninitialized constant Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am trying to experiment on an open source application application .

when i run

```
$ rake db:create
```

Following is the stacktrace

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Cucumber
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/home/BigBangTheory/Desktop/spot-us/lib/tasks/cucumber.rake:13
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1882:in `in_namespace'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:910:in `namespace'
/home/BigBangTheory/Desktop/spot-us/lib/tasks/cucumber.rake:12
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/BigBangTheory/Desktop/spot-us/Rakefile:9
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Cucumber!](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber)

```
[~/railsapp]$ script/plugin install git://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber.git
```